# Finding the current namespace of current php class files in PhpStorm 2017.1.4

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm creating a new php class in PhpStorm 2017.1.4 file for a project via the below window:

[image: Create New PHP Class dialog box]

I need to set a '**Namespace**' for the class file, how can I find the current name space of the other php class files in the project? There's a prompt to use Ctrl + Space to open the blue dropdown but I'm unsure what to select. Is there a way to tell if the  other class files use one of these options?

I've tried following [these instructions on jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/configuring-php-namespaces-in-a-project.html?utm_content=2017.1&utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=PS&search=namespace) but the notification (pictured below) pops up in the bottom right of project window and it doesn't really tell me what I'm looking for so I think I'm using the wrong feature.

[image: PSR Detection Notification]

I'm new to php so I've never done this before. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you have a folder in your e.g. called 'classes' so each php class inside this folder whil has 'namespace Classes;' And same for subfolders simply add them like the folder structure is

Comment: > how can I find the current name space of the other php class files in the project? -- Could you please clarify that? Probably by providing an example? Ctrl+Space is already providing you with namespaces available in a current project

Comment: @Ástþór Alot of other 'classes' or class files have been created by another dev on my team (who isn't available to ask) so a 'Namespace' should have been entered in the input field in the 'Create New PHP Class' window above when those files were created. I was wondering if there was a way to find out what had been entered as 'Namespace' when the files were created. I hope that sense.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend just guessing namespaces based on their presence in a project. You either know that you're using a namespace in a current file/class or you don't use it. It looks like you need to start with basics first http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php